# Implicit async custom validators (custom validators that take 2 arguments) are deprecated in mongoose >= 4.9.0

Tags: node.js, mongoose, validator.js

I'm using mongoose 4.9.0. Whilst the code below works, I get a warning like the following:

> (node:24769) DeprecationWarning: Implicit async custom validators
>   (custom validators that take 2 arguments) are deprecated in mongoose >= 4.9.0. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#async-custom-validators for more info.

I suspect the error is coming from the model validators.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const isEmail = require('validator/lib/isEmail');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    validate: [{ validator: isEmail, msg: 'Invalid email.' }],
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

The only custom validator I seem to have is `isEmail` from the [`validator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) library, which given an string value returns whether it is valid or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a sneaky mistake in your custom validator.

[`isEmail`](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js#validators) function from the [`validator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) library takes 2 parameters, even though the second one is completely optional.

```
isEmail(str [, options])
```

You can prevent mongoose from seeing it by creating a function on top of it:

```
validate: [{ validator: value => isEmail(value), msg: 'Invalid email.' }]
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on the mongoose Documentation you can remove the warning by setting the isAsync attribute of the validator to false. Mongoose assumes that all functions that take in two parameters are asynchronous

```
validate: [{ isAsync:false, validator: isEmail, msg: 'Invalid email.' }]
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#async-custom-validators

Answer (score 2):

```
//add validator to user model schema 

var validator = require('validator');

validate:{
       validator: (value)=>{

         return validator.isEmail(value);  

       },

       message:'{VALUE} is not a valid Email'

  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make copy for the below codes and will work without any errors

```
email: {
    type: String,
    required : true,
    lowercase : true,
    unique:true,
    validate: { 
    validator:function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
},   message: '{email} Invalid' 
     }
  }
```

Comment: it would be helpful to point out what was the problem, not just past code

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM

```
import validate from 'mongoose-validator'

[...]
    email: {
      type: String,
      validate: validate({
        validator: 'isEmail',
        message: 'is not valid',
      })
    }
[...]
```

SOLUTION

```
import validate from 'mongoose-validator'

const isEmail = validate.validatorjs.isEmail

[...]
    email: {
      type: String,
      validate: {
        validator: value => isEmail(value),
        message: 'is not valid'
      }
    }
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var validator = require('validator');
   validate: {
        validator: (value) => validator.isEmail(value),
        message: "{VALUE} is not a valid email"
    }
```

Comment: Please add some details description, so that anyone can understand your answer at a glance.