# Async custom validators mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I'm trying to do some async custom validations in mongoose@6.6.1
`

```
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tags: {
    type: Array,
    validate: {
      validator: async function (v) {
        return await validateTags(v);
      },
      message: "A Course should have atleast one tags.",
    },
  }
});

const validateTags = async (v) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return v && v.length > 0;
  }, 2000);
};
```

`

This is to check whether the given input has atleast one value in it's array. But I am not getting validated properly. Reffered [Mongoose: the isAsync option for custom validators is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542295/mongoose-the-isasync-option-for-custom-validators-is-deprecated). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to call the `validateTags` to see what it returns?
Aswer: `undefined` and also it returns immediately, it does not wait for the timeout to fire.

The `setTimeout` with `return` does not work the way you think.

```
const validateTags = async (v) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // the result of the line bellow is returned to the caller of this function
    // and that is the setTimeout not the validateTags !!!
    return v && v.length > 0;
  }, 2000);
};
```

Try this instead:

```
const validateTags = async (v) => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(v && v.length > 0);
      }, 2000);
  });
};
```